# Why does my Open GL Triangle cover up my whole Viewport

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am using the android Open GL tutorial to get an understanding on Open GL and I tried to implement my own SimpleTriangle drawing that should work exactly like the other Triangle class however it takes up the entire screen.

```
public class SimpleTriangle {

private static float x, y;
private static float[] triangleCoords = {

        x, 5.773502692f, 0.0f, // top
        x-(float)5, y-2.886851346f, 0.0f,
        x+(float)5, y-2.886851346f, 0.0f

};

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;

private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f };

public SimpleTriangle(float xInt, float yInt){

    x = xInt;
    y = yInt;

    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            triangleCoords.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}

}
```

I feel the problem lies with my Matrix.setLookAt method as I don't purely understand how to set up my viewing range.

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private static final String TAG = "MyGLRenderer";
private SimpleTriangle firstTriangle;
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

private float mAngle;

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    firstTriangle = new SimpleTriangle(0f, 0f);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    firstTriangle.draw(scratch);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
    }
}
```

}

To clarify, this is the exact tutorial that is here: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html
I am just trying to explicitly state where I want a triangle.

So why does my triangle take up my entire viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your coordinates and transformations, it makes sense that your triangle would cover the whole window.

Your triangle is in the z = 0.0 plane. Rounding the coordinates to the next whole number for easier readability, the `(x, y)` coordinates of the 3 vertices are:

```
(0, 6)
(-5, -3)
(5, -3)
```

So the triangle is about 10 units wide and 9 units high, centered around the origin.

Now walking through the transformations. `mRotationMatrix` is an identity matrix since it rotates by 0 degrees, so it does not come into play.

Then comes `mViewMatrix`, which is set here:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Based on the arguments, your eye point is `(0, 0, -3)`, looking at `(0, 0, 0)`. Since your triangle is in the z = 0 plane, the eye point is 3 units from the triangle, looking at it head on.

Finally, the projection matrix is applied, which is set up here:

```
Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
```

The Android documentation does not document the parameters in detail, but the parameters seem to match the ones of the legacy OpenGL `glFrustum()` ([doc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml)) call. So the left/right/bottom/top values are measured at the near plane distance.

As previously established, the triangle is 3 units from the eye point, which is the same as the near plane distance (7th argument of `frustum`). So the triangle is exactly on the near plane. At the near plane, the extent of the coordinates within the frustum is given by the 3rd to 6th argument, which is `(-ratio, ratio)` for the x-coordinates, and `(-1, 1)` for the y-coordinates.

Since your triangle is much larger than the `(-ratio, ratio) x (-1, 1)` dimensions of the frustum at that distance, it covers the whole window, and then some. Unless the aspect ratio is extremely large.

If you want your triangle to appear smaller, you'll probably want to increase the eye distance (5th argument of `setLookAtM()`, and adjust the near/far plane distances (7th and 8th argument of `frustumM`) accordingly. A typical set of values would have your eye distance somewhere around the middle between the near and far distances.

Comment: This was it. I guess I wasn't aware of Open GL using units rather than coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The scratch matrix that you pass to `SimpleTriangle.draw(float[])` doesn't seem correct to me.

From what I can tell you get the proper MVP matrix using `mViewMatrix` and `mProjectionMatrix`.  Where is `mRotationMatrix` being set though?  You rotate it by `mAngle` but if the matrix is all zeros to begin with it won't change.  If `mRotationMatrix` is in fact all zeros, when you multiply it by `mMVPMatrix`, this will result in a matrix of all zeros.

I would try commenting out the `Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);` line and see if that works.